# C++ Spirit Boost: Making a input iterator into a forward iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, iterator, boost-spirit

So I'm very new to Boost but I'm running into problems trying to do some of the most basic of things in my win32 application project in vs2010.

I have gone into my vs2010 project properties and made sure that my include files are looking in the right places, and when I build I don't get errors including hpp files from boost in my stdafx.h, however when I read the documentation on their site here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/multi_pass.html I just get a bunch of basic errors like multi_pass is undefined.

I only need boost for one thing, and that is to create a forward operator from my current input operator so I can pass it through a function. Below is the declaration for my input operator.

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eof;
```

I found an alternative solution on that same page where the std::basic_istream_iterator is actually a forward operator but when I compile I get an error saying that basic_istream_iterator is not part of the std library.

In the end I'm just really new to iterators themselves and boost. I would like to know how I can get my input iterator transformed into a forward iterator so I can iterator through a file.

Comment: There is no `std::basic_istream_iterator`; there's a `std::istream_iterator` however.

Comment: If `multi_pass` is undefined, you're not including the right headers.  Did you follow the "complete source code" link from the multi_pass documentation page mentioned in your question - i.e. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/example/support/multi_pass.cpp ?  Make sure you're including the headers listed there.  Out of curiosity - you say you want a forward iterator so you can "pass it through a function", and "iterator through a file" - is that a Standard library function you want to use it with?  Which one?  Why isn't an input iterator enough? (there are valid reasons)

Comment: Thank you Tony, yes I am using it for the search function in <algorithm> which takes forward iterators for the first and second parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the commenter siad, you need to include the right support headers.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_multi_pass.hpp>
```

Howeever, the simplest way is:

```
 std::ifstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::binary);
 file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

 // use the ready-made:

 boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(file), l;

 // parse!
 book ok = qi::parse(f, l, my_grammar);
```